# Possible to run a SOCKS proxy in a docker container that is available in other containers in a stack?

Tags: docker, socks, datomic

I've been trying unsuccessfully to run a SOCKS proxy inside a docker container that can then be used by an application running in another container. To give the big picture, here is the `docker-compose.yml` file that I'm using with `docker stack up -c` to launch the containers.

```
version: "3.1"

secrets:
  aws_access_key:
    external: true
  aws_secret_access_key:
    external: true

services:
  web:
    image: ezmiller/datemo-nginx-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  datomic-socks-proxy:
    image: ezmiller/datomic-socks-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    environment:
      - PORT=8182
    secrets:
      - aws_access_key
      - aws_secret_access_key

  datemo:
    image: ezmiller/datemo:latest
    depends_on:
      - web
      - datomic-socks-proxy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I'm able to get the SOCKS proxy running locally inside the `datomic-socks-proxy` container, but it's not reachable from within the `datemo` container, which is where the proxy is needed.

The method for testing the proxy is as follows:

```
curl -x socks5h://127.0.0.1:8182 http://entry.****.us-east-2.datomic.net:8182/)
```

Is it possible to share a SOCKS proxy this way? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: I bet 127.0.0.1 is wrong (it always refers to "this" container wherever you're calling it from); does using `datomic-socks-proxy` as a host name work?

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference. :(